# Should I allow \n store into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have `textarea` in my form

when user type **Enter** key, it will store `\n` into database

should I allow `\n` to store into mySql database? or should I `str_replace` it, what if user type `abc\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n` press lots of **Enter**, is any way to **trim** `\n` front and end

Comment: That completely depends on what you want.

Comment: use trim() to get rid of leading or trailing "\n" characters; str_replace() if you want to reduce multiple line breaks between lines of content

Comment: how much space does \n taken in database will it affect query or LIKE%%

Comment: If there are line breaks in your data then it's probably a somewhat large text field and you probably should not be using like on it anyways. But remember, if you strip out line breaks when you put it in, what will the data look like when you take it out? Presumably, you store the data because there is some use for it later. Will that break the use? A user typing \n\n\n\n\n doesn't seem like a big issue to me since it would likely be rare and it's a few extra characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to you on what you want to do with the data. If you want to allow multiple line breaks then do it! If you don't then don't! Here is some code that may help you:

```
// trim leading and trailing line breaks, spaces, tabs, etc.
$string = trim($string);

// Replace multiple line breaks with one:
$string = preg_replace("/\n+/", "\n", $string);
```

Comment: What happens when the piece of text is markdown encoded and starts with an indented code block?